# Why data fetching from Redis is very slow on AWS Instance

Tags: php, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, redis

First I installed redis on my local machine(Ubuntu 14.04) using following links.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-redis
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-redis-server-as-a-session-handler-for-php-on-ubuntu-14-04

I am using hashes for storing data in redis. The query took about 300 ms when there is a db hit and took 60-70ms when it fetches from redis. After that I do the same thing on my ubuntu AMI which is m4 large but unfortunately I din't see any changes in response time and sometimes it took more time than db hit. I don't know where I am missing.

```
    $this->redis = New \Redis();
    $this->redis->connect('127.0.0.1', 6379);
    $this->redis-hset($id, $key, serialize($result));
    if($this->redis->hexists($id,$key)) {
         return $this->redis->hget($id, $key);
    }
```

And I am sure that it fetches data from redis when it is available in redis.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest trying another instance type. The m4.large is only a 2 core instance type, maybe try a 4 core? Or use the AWS elastic-cache redis service.

Might find some helpful info [here](https://redislabs.com/blog/5-tips-for-running-redis-over-aws#.VpG0r_krLIV) as well.

Comment: Redis being monothread, increasing the number of cores should have any effect (assuming you only have one redis instance)

Comment: @PascalLeMerrer that is true, but this server is hosting both Redis and the PHP web server, and possibly other things, so increasing the number of CPUs may help the overall performance being tested. Moving to a dedicated Redis server such as ElastiCache, as enderv suggests would also be helpful in pinpointing the performance issue.

Answer (score 0):

Benchmark serialization time - for more complex data serialization/unserialization is much longer than actual writing to redis. ( check http://kiss-web.blogspot.com/2016/02/memcached-vs-redisphpredis-vs-predis-vs.html )